# what is the good way to add 1 in column values if value greater than 2 python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I want to add 1 in column values if column value is greater than 2

```
here is my dataframe

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,2],'flag':[1,1,0,1,1,1,5,1,1,0,1,1,1]})
```

****df_out****

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,2],'flag':[1,1,0,1,1,1,6,1,1,0,1,1,1]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with add `1`:

```
df.loc[df.A.gt(2), 'flag'] += 1
print (df)
    A  flag
0   1     1
1   1     1
2   1     0
3   1     1
4   1     1
5   1     1
6   3     6
7   2     1
8   2     1
9   2     0
10  2     1
11  2     1
12  2     1
```

Or:

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df.A.gt(2), df['flag'] + 1, df['flag'])
```

EDIT:

```
mean = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['x'], bins))['y'].transform('mean')
df['flag'] = np.where(mean.gt(2), df['y'] + 1, df['y'])
```

And then:

```
x= df.groupby(pd.cut(df['x'], bins))['y'].apply(lambda x:abs(x-np.mean(x)))
```

Comment: x= df.groupby(pd.cut(df['x'], bins))['y'].apply(lambda x:abs(x-np.mean(x)))  here in this code how to adjust if mean greater 2 add +1

Comment: @Nickel - Do you think change `apply` to `transform` ?

Comment: @Nickel - then change `df.A.gt(2)` to `df.groupby(pd.cut(df['x'], bins))['y'].transform(lambda x:abs(x-np.mean(x))).gt(2)`

Comment: but here i want to do if mean greater than 2 add 1 and then do x-mean(x)